# How JDBCTemplate queryForObject works. Specifically, the new Object[] {} part

Tags: jdbctemplate

I have this piece of example code:

```
public Post findById(Long id) {
    String sql = "select id, title, text from post where id = ?";

    return template.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {id}, getPostRowMapper());

}
```

I don't understand what the `new Object[] {id}` is doing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a sql statement with a variable in it (the question mark sign), then you need to supply the variables that will be placed into that statement where the question marks are.

`new Object[] {id}` tells us which variables should be put in places where the question marks are.

`new Object[] {}` creates an empty array of objects. `new Object[] {id}` creates an array of objects with one item in it - the `Long id`, which is the function parameter.

So, let's say id is equal to 1. In that case, the question mark

`where id = ?`

Will be replaced with `1`

`where id = 1`